# Will the constructor get called on orientation change?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple class, where on my constructor i am calling a method. Will the constructor be re-called on orientation change.

```
public class ClasName{   
   public ClassName(){
      MethodCalled();
   }    
}
```

Comment: A constructor will be called everytime when an instance of the `ClassName` gets created. So the question should be - is an object of this class created when orientation changes?

Comment: An Acitivity does not need to have a constructor overridden therefore, all your logic should go in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

You should call your `MethodCalled()` method in the [onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method rather than the constructor. This will ensure it is called on an orientation change as well as when the activity starts for the first time.

Typically you will never need to override the constructor for your activity since the instance is fully managed by Android. You should override the [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) callback method instead. This is only called when the activity is created, not restored from a previous state.

You may find the tutorial for [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) useful, as well as the overview in [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).